# Como extrair somente números de uma string?

Tags: c#, string

Quero extrair somente os numeros de um CPF que está numa string nesse formato;

> 111.222.333-44

Tem que retornar apenas:

> 11122233344

Comment: Se não me engano, `\d` inclui letras também.

Comment: Use apenas `\d`.

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer. Numa string "abc0d1e2" vc quer "012" ou "0"?

Comment: @EricLemes, já esclareci na pergunta.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Consegui:

Esse código funcionou:

```
String.Join("", System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(stringAqui, @"[^\d]"))
```

- `^` dentro de um conjunto(`[]`) significa negação.
- `\d` atalho para `0-9`, ou seja, números;

Em poucas palavras a `regex` significa tudo que não é número;

Comment: Uma outra opção: `Método Regex.Replace (String, String)`

Comment: @Marconi claro, pode sim

Answer (score 6):

Para esse casos não tem porque ter complicação, faça com `substring()`:

```
cpf.Substring(0, 3) + cpf.Substring(4, 3) + cpf.Substring(8, 3) + cpf.Substring(12, 2)
```

Melhor ainda:

```
string.Concat(cpf.AsSpan(0, 3), cpf.AsSpan(4, 3), cpf.AsSpan(8, 3), cpf.AsSpan(12, 2))
```

E ainda pode usar uma sintaxe melhor, mas a performance volta ser mais ou menos:

```
cpf[0..3] + cpf[4..7] + cpf[8..11] + cpf[12..14]
```

Mas embora a pergunta possa interpretada como resolver isso só para o CPF, ela também pode ser feita para limpar e deixar só dígitos numéricos de qualquer tipo de dado onde não se conhece o formato. Nesse caso teria que fazer isto:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(cpf.Length);
foreach (var letra in cpf) if (Char.IsDigit(letra)) sb.Append(letra);
formatado = sb.ToString();
```

É o mesmo efeito do LINQ postado pelo Samuel (se não tiver que se preocupar com performance é uma boa solução e mais curta, tem que analisar qual vale mais a pena usar) o que é uma boa resposta.

Fiz um código comparando as opções postadas aqui:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Diagnostics;
using  System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        const int total = 1_000_000;
        var cpf = "111.222.333-44";
        var formatado = "";
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            formatado = cpf.Substring(0, 3) + cpf.Substring(4, 3) + cpf.Substring(8, 3) + cpf.Substring(12, 2);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Restart();
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            formatado = string.Concat(cpf.AsSpan(0, 3), cpf.AsSpan(4, 3), cpf.AsSpan(8, 3), cpf.AsSpan(12, 2));
        }
        sw.Stop();
        WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Restart();
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            formatado = cpf[0..3] + cpf[4..7] + cpf[8..11] + cpf[12..14];
        }
        sw.Stop();
        WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Restart();
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            var sb = new StringBuilder(cpf.Length);
            foreach (var letra in cpf) if (Char.IsDigit(letra)) sb.Append(letra);
            formatado = sb.ToString();
        }
        sw.Stop();
        WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Restart();
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            formatado = string.Join("", cpf.ToCharArray().Where(Char.IsDigit));
        }
        sw.Stop();
        WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Restart();
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            formatado = String.Join("", Regex.Split(cpf, @"[^\d]"));
        }
        sw.Stop();
        WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Restart();
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+");            
            var result = "";
            foreach (Match m in r.Matches(cpf)) result += m.Value;
            formatado = result;
        }
        sw.Stop();
        WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JOUIw7). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/BenchmarkString.cs).

Fiz o teste na minha máquina porque esses sites de IDE online não são confiáveis e o método melhor é usando o Benchmark.NET, e deu:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19041.329 (2004/?/20H1)
Intel Core i7-7700K CPU 4.20GHz (Kaby Lake), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=5.0.100-preview.1.20155.7
  [Host]     : .NET Core 5.0.0 (CoreCLR 5.0.20.12005, CoreFX 5.0.20.12005), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 5.0.0 (CoreCLR 5.0.20.12005, CoreFX 5.0.20.12005), X64 RyuJIT


|        Method |        Mean |    Error |   StdDev |  Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|-------------- |------------:|---------:|---------:|-------:|------:|------:|----------:|
|     Substring |    55.52 ns | 0.248 ns | 0.232 ns | 0.0421 |     - |     - |     176 B |
|          Span |    24.67 ns | 0.097 ns | 0.086 ns | 0.0115 |     - |     - |      48 B |
|         Range |    53.06 ns | 0.260 ns | 0.231 ns | 0.0421 |     - |     - |     176 B |
|       Foreach |    44.22 ns | 0.255 ns | 0.238 ns | 0.0363 |     - |     - |     152 B |
|          Linq |   191.17 ns | 0.752 ns | 0.703 ns | 0.1147 |     - |     - |     480 B |
|    RegexSplit |   396.71 ns | 2.431 ns | 2.274 ns | 0.0763 |     - |     - |     320 B |
|  RegexReplace |   366.67 ns | 0.901 ns | 0.704 ns | 0.0110 |     - |     - |      48 B |
|  RegexMatches | 1,780.55 ns | 6.015 ns | 5.332 ns | 0.8678 |     - |     - |    3632 B |
| RegexMatchesG |   818.62 ns | 3.186 ns | 2.980 ns | 0.5465 |     - |     - |    2288 B |
```

Poderia ter testado ambientes diferentes, mas achei que não valia a pena.

Quem quiser o código:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;

[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class Program {
    public string cpf = "111.222.333-44";
    public static void Main(string[] args) => BenchmarkSwitcher.FromAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly).Run(args);
    [Benchmark]
    public string Substring() => cpf.Substring(0, 3) + cpf.Substring(4, 3) + cpf.Substring(8, 3) + cpf.Substring(12, 2);
    [Benchmark]
    public string Span() => string.Concat(cpf.AsSpan(0, 3), cpf.AsSpan(4, 3), cpf.AsSpan(8, 3), cpf.AsSpan(12, 2));
    [Benchmark]
    public string Range() => cpf[0..3] + cpf[4..7] + cpf[8..11] + cpf[12..14];
    [Benchmark]
    public string Foreach() {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(cpf.Length);
        foreach (var letra in cpf) if (Char.IsDigit(letra)) sb.Append(letra);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    [Benchmark]
    public string Linq() => string.Join("", cpf.ToCharArray().Where(Char.IsDigit));
    [Benchmark]
    public string RegexSplit() => String.Join("", Regex.Split(cpf, @"[^\d]"));
    [Benchmark]
    public string RegexReplace() => Regex.Replace(cpf, @"[^\d]", "");
    [Benchmark]
    public string RegexMatches() {
        Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+");
        var result = "";
        foreach (Match m in r.Matches(cpf)) result += m.Value;
        return result;
    }
    [Benchmark]
    public string RegexMatchesG() {
        Regex r = new Regex(@"\G");
        var result = "";
        foreach (Match m in r.Matches(cpf)) result += m.Value;
        return result;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/BenchmarkString2.cs).

Limpar os dígitos foi mais rápido e mais genérico que a solução que pega os pedaços individuais. Ainda há espaço para fazer a composição específica usando `Span` para melhor performance, mas a limpeza com um laço simples é bem competitiva.

Isso me deu a ideia de tentar criar um `StringBuilder` na *stack* para ser mais rápido ainda, mas eu sei que ele teria limitações, ele não poderia ser exatamente um *builder*, teria que ser um *buffer* e com tamanho máximo relativamente pequeno, por isso não poderia usar em qualquer situação.

Não que seja errado, mas eu não usaria RegEx em hipótese alguma. É uma solução menos legível sempre, com performance absurdamente ruim e nem sempre funciona como a pessoa espera. Sou adepto da citação do Jamie Zawinski

> Quando você tenta resolver um problema com RegEx você passa ter dois problemas.

Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre isso aqui porque não é o foco da pergunta.

Comment: Pesquisando mais sobre performance usando AsSpan, encontrei esse [artigo](https://www.eximiaco.tech/pt/2019/06/27/encontrar-e-extrair-um-numero-em-uma-string-em-c-incluindo-spant/), então resolvi testar a sua implementação de AsSpan com a implementação que tem no artigo. Como resultado, a implementação do artigo foi melhor, acredito que seja pelo fato de string.Concat ser gerenciado pelo GC. +1

Comment: @SamuelRenanGonçalvesVaz não sei se entendi, o `AsSpan()` foi a melhor de todas. No caso usei o `Concat()`porque era o requerimento desse problema, não tinha como não fazer assim, tem como não usar, mas não daria o mesmo resultado pretendido, eu quis que sempre desse o mesmo resultado pra ninguém falar que em deles foi mais rápido mas deu outro resultado ainda que parecido. De qualquer forma mostre o teste que fez, pode ser que dê para fazer algo que eu nem vi. Obrigado. Alguém não gostou e deu negativo também.

Comment: @Maniero, Fui refazer o teste que fiz em modo "debug" e percebi que estava considerando apenas até 0..3 nesse caso eu falhei na implementação. Parabéns pela resposta.

Comment: @SamuelRenanGonçalvesVaz é tem que fazer em Release.

Comment: @SamuelRenanGonçalvesVaz melhorei para falar da limpeza em vez de composição. Quem sabe o negativo foi porque a pessoa achou que só valia se fosse limpeza.

Comment: ficou ótimo. Sobre a parte que fala de regex, concordo plenamente, pena que não tem como adicionar +2 na resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Uma solução sem usar `Regex`:

```
var cpf = "111.222.333-44"

string.Join("", cpf.ToCharArray().Where(Char.IsDigit));
```

[Outras formas de fazer também](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-a-number-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Outra solução:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestGetOnlyNumbers()
    {
        Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+");            
        string result = "";
        foreach (Match m in r.Matches("111.222.333-44"))
            result += m.Value;

        Assert.AreEqual("11122233344", result);
    }
```

A pegadinha é que precisa dar multiplos matches no que é número. Se vc usar o método Regex.Match, só pega o primeiro (111).

Comment: você pode utilizar a flag `g` que continua procurando.